# Can There Be Two Installations of Magento 2.0.7 With Only One MagentoUser

Tags: cron, file-permissions, magento-2.0.7

Pretty much is what the question says. I would like to have a development environment for development of my own "make an offer box" module, and since I have 0 clue on how to do that, I want to install some sample modules for reverse engineering.  I know its backwards, buts its how I've learned computers since i was 12.  Rip it apart, and learn backwards.

I digress, regardless of my reasons, I need to know if I can have just one magento_user for the cron tasks, and the file system permissions, or if I need two different users for the different home directories/ installations.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call learning through reverse engineering backwards, I think if more people did it they would have a deeper understanding of how things work rather. I originally found the question odd as I assumed you were looking to have a single Magento admin user.

After re-reading I'm assuming your question is instead can you run two installs of Magento with the same system user, and the answer is yes absolutely. You can run as many installs as you wish using a single system user. You can either run them on a single domain name in sub-directories or add VirtualHosts linking to each sub-directory. Depending on how technical you want to get you could even spin up unique environments for the two separate installs using something such as [this vagrant box](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers) provided by a core team member.

Comment: i am actually looking to just have a testing server such that dont really have to do anything to get it functioning other than add a couple of lines to the already existing magento_user's crontab, and yes reverse engineer learning (the hacker way as I call it) is honestly the best way.  It would obviously be in a different virtual host, but one that wouldnt be exposed, and would obviously have its own directory

Comment: Assuming you have an existing server running an existing instance, it should just be as simple as creating a new folder with the code for the new instance, setting the permissions correctly within the folder, creating a new DB to be used for it and then run the setup. You can also add a new crontab entry with the new path if you want the crons running.

Comment: i just dont want to screw up my production environment (making me money)  site, while i tinker.  Thanks for the quick response.  I know this is completely off topic, but might you have some links for module development handy maybe?  There is no direct-message for SE (a fall point imho), and you were so quick to get back to me.

Comment: Ahh, if it's on a production environment then yes you need to be very careful. You don't want to introduce security problems from code you're working on that may give somebody server access. I would highly recommend looking through Alan's posts http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2

Comment: Hey thanks for link, and fyi the new virtual host will be Deny All; Allow from [Internal Subnet Only] in the http.conf file so no worries, and on top of that i will add a specific iptables rule at not only the switch, but also on the server.  Double overkill ikr? but have you actually looked at your fail2ban logs... Exactly